# Taking screen shot of iframe within a modal box programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, screenshot

I have researched and the library which I thought might suit was: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com

But the problem is that it parses the DOM hence it doesn't parses the iframe/modalbox (since they are not the part of DOM?).

This is how the modal box looks like:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this so that when I click on Finish it takes the screenshot which I would then save as base64 and send to user email?

Comment: Unless you own the site in the iframe, you cannot do this by any method. This type of access is explicitly prevented by modern browsers for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I think this is the answer. You can post it as answer and I will mark it as accepted.